# How to use 2 differents owlcarousel version togheter

Tags: owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I need to have 2 slides sync, that's why I have used owlcarousel2, but I', working on a website that is all developed by owlcarousel1.
I have problems to use these togheter.

Is there a way to dont break each other?
Or is there a way to sync two slides by owlcarousel1?

Thank you